# Is it possible to calculate area of polygons from GPS points without POSTGIS

Tags: polygon, gps, area

I am new with GIS.

Assume we use the UTM30N coordinate system.

Is it possible to calculate an area (say a square box) by the 4 given points? (assume the points are in order, and the coordinates are very close to each other.)

Corollary, is it possible to calculate the area of a polygon?

Can this be done without the use of PostGIS?

Comment: Using pencil and paper? Using a hand calculator? Using a spreadsheet? Can be easily done with all three if you assume the points are on a flat plane, which is true to a high degree of precision for close points. Lovely example in part 3 here: http://www.wikihow.com/Calculate-the-Area-of-a-Polygon Now, what are you actually asking?

Comment: Good point, sorry to not be clear. Given that the large nature of the coordinate points. What units do I use?

Comment: Use meters. UTM coordinates represent distance in meters from the zone's reference point. Here's a quick and simple overview: https://www.maptools.com/tutorials/utm/quick_guide

Comment: As with any projection, there are scale issues to consider, see this [very detailed answer](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/calculate-distortion-outside-a-utm-zone). However, for small areas, you can simply work in meters and get the area directly as if you were on a 2D plane.

Comment: Most GPS specific software has the ability to give you the area of a track or just with measuring tools between points. And loading your points into QGIS or some other GUI based mapping software would allow the same thing, as does pen-and-paper suggested by the other comments. So no, PostGIS isn't required (nor is GIS at all really), and speed, accuracy, and ease-of-use are all trade-off factors to be balanced for your desired purpose.