# how to calculate area if it is falling in two utm zones

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, area

I am using ArcGIS 10.1. How do I calculate an accurate **area** measure for a polygon, where portions of it are falling in two zones, i.e. **UTM ZONE 44 & 45 (India)**?

Comment: do you want area in just those two zones? or area in each zone?

Comment: Accurate is relative here.  Have you looked at this yet: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/dealing-with-data-that-spreads-across-utm-zones

Comment: And this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31701/calculate-distortion-outside-a-utm-zone/31711#31711

Comment: This is a FAQ: see http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=polygon+area+accurate+calculate .  The short answer: use an equal-area projection.