# How to quantify projection distortion using ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I am trying to figure out a workflow to quantify the amount of distortion for different projections throughout a given area of interest.  I am thinking in the form that you would do a relative accuracy assessment.  The difference between the known (direction, distance, area, etc) vs the projected.  I envision the area of interest covered in a grid of points, lines and polygons (or whatever combination of vector i need for the calcs) and calculating the values both ways.  Is there something like that out there?  What would be the steps needed to take for each distortion?  I would probably only care about distance, area, and direction.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-to-create-an-accurate-tissot-indicatrix

Comment: I am not sure the link fully answers my questions, but it is enough to keep me busy and perhaps put me in the right direction.  What is proper etiquette for this post?  Should I delete it?

Comment: You are welcome to delete it, Rex, but we tend to keep posts-closed-as-duplicates around because they can show up in searches and serve as links to the answers.