# Angular distance between Grid and True North given Lat/Long

Tags: utm

As part of a project that uses UTM coordinates I am trying to find a formula to compute the angle (with sign) between the grid north and the true north. I understand this is called `meridian convergence`.

I am already able to get the correct easting and northing, but I cannot find a reference for a formula that would give me the angle given a single location.

I know that I can derive it mapping multiple points and computing then the angles between the lines that connect them as suggested, for example, [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/5075/45254), but if possible I would like to avoid it.

Does such an equation exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more extensive search I found [this document](http://earth-info.nga.mil/GandG/publications/tm8358.2/TM8358_2.pdf).

At page 18/19 there is exactly the equation requested:

[image]

with the various parameters defined in the preceding pages.