# Repository for .prj files

Tags: coordinate-system

Do you know any repository where can i find .prj files?

I am looking for local coordinate system: Warszawa 75 (Warsaw 75)

I found myself this [repository](http://spatialreference.org/)
 but the .prj which i found [there](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/43/) seems to be broken.

Comment: The oens I would search for are : Pulkovo 1942 Adj 1958 Poland Zone I.prj, Pulkovo 1942 Adj 1958 Poland Zone II.prj, Pulkovo 1942 Adj 1958 Poland Zone III.prj, Pulkovo 1942 Adj 1958 Poland Zone IV.prj, Pulkovo 1942 Adj 1958 Poland Zone V.prj AND ETRS 1989 Poland CS2000 Zone 5.prj, ETRS 1989 Poland CS2000 Zone 6.prj, ETRS 1989 Poland CS2000 Zone 7.prj, ETRS 1989 Poland CS2000 Zone 8.prj OR ETRS 1989 Poland CS92.prj with the last one being my best guess.

Comment: if you assign a projection, transform to another projection and your data is not in the right place. Your original guess of which projection your data is in was wrong. You should start over and discover the correct prj for your data.

Comment: You're right, but the point is that I surely know that the data is in this coordinate system and it is not a guess (i know it from the data author).

Comment: The clearest way that the data author could communicate the coordinate system to you is to supply you with the .prj file (or the equivalent in a metadata format).  Otherwise, we have to suspect some kind of miscommunication or even misunderstanding on the author's part.  Although it's possible that a standard .prj file is in error, that is a far less likely explanation.

Comment: unprojected data (no prj) overlaid with projected data (the same crs) will produce proof of the suspected projection.

Comment: The Esri/prj definitions are incorrect. The OGC human-readable defn looks better: PROJCS["unnamed",GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",DATUM["unknown",SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Oblique_Stereographic"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",52.2385990793],PARAMETER["central_meridian",21.0114585301],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",-0],UNIT["Meter",1]] BUT the projection name should be "Double_Stereographic". GRS80 can't be used for Warsaw 72, so the GCS/Datum info is wrong.

Comment: Based on other stereographic-based definitions for Poland, the scale factor probably shouldn't be 1.0 and there should be false easting and false northing values. EPSG doesn't have any definitions that match these values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides agreeing with Brad / whubber on everything they've said, I suggest a google search, an examination of your metadata, and an examination of the coordinates in ArcMap.  Drop it in a fresh map, and look at the coordinates.  This may give you some clues.  As for the other info I've suggested, see all the comments at [this link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/shp-with-unknown-coordinate-system/8776#8776) as well.

Copy and paste the name of the original shapefile in google (including the .shp extension).  It may reveal nothing, but you may also be surprised whet you find out!!  People underestimate google searches!!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is also a site called http://epsg2prj.org/.  But seems to be down at the moment.

Answer (score -1):

PROJCS["PUWG_42_Strefa_3",GEOGCS["GCS_Pulkovo_1942",DATUM["D_Pulkovo_1942",SPHEROID["Krasovsky_1940",6378245,298.3]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",3500000],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",15],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",1],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/102/

Comment: I worte that I was looking for Warszawa 75 not PUWG 42.

Comment: You wrote:  i want to transform shapefile to well known coordinate system (PUWG 1992)

Comment: anyhoo, the prj was here: PROJCS["Stereographic_North_Pole",GEOGCS["GRS 1980(IUGG, 1980)",DATUM["D_unknown",SPHEROID["GRS80",6378137,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Stereographic_North_Pole"],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",52.2385990793],PARAMETER["central_meridian",21.0114585301],PARAMETER["scale_factor",1],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",-0],UNIT["Meter",1]]

Comment: Yes, but this is just a mistake. This is not .prj for Warszawa 75. That's the point!

Comment: I'd suggest you rewrote the question as it's not entirely clear what you do actually want

Comment: I just want .prj file for Warsaw 75 coordinate system (as i already wrote)

Comment: and you have it