# List of methods of determining the projection of a shapefile when .prj is missing

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practices for identifying the unknown coordinate system of a Shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/best-practices-for-identifying-the-unknown-coordinate-system-of-a-shapefile)

It would be helpful to mention what information is needed to perform each technique. What are situations in which this may happen, and the best ways to deal with it?