# Help me convert this US Lambert Conformal Conic Google Maps Projection to Australia

Tags: javascript, coordinate-system, google-maps, australia

Following on from this question: [Identify what projection this Australian map uses?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/70255/identify-what-projection-this-australian-map-uses) <- this is the sort of map i want to load in

I need help changing the bits necessary in this example of Lambert Projection in Google Maps to make it work with Australian tiles instead: [Lambert equal area azimuthal projection Google Map](http://facstaff.unca.edu/mcmcclur/GoogleMaps/Projections/Lambert.html) which apparently uses these formulae: [Lambert Conformal Conic Projection -- from Wolfram MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertConformalConicProjection.html)

**[Here is my attempts so far, changing what i think needs changing, but it must not be enough](http://dev.httech.com.au/shoebox/map.php)**

- its a bit confusing for me, im a web developer
- i will be adding the tiles at a later stage
- in my version i made it so when you click around it shows the coords, but as you do this the ones it shows are not in australia, so thus my problem
- in the original demo it centers and loads tiles 001 & 101, in mine it does not
- in my version i made it try to load all tiles so you can see which ones in the error console

**Thanks for your time.**

Heres is the original javascript it uses as seen at that site: 
(you may notice it uses google maps api v2, not the latest v3 available due to its age)

```
var phi0 = 10*Math.PI/180;
var phi1 = 20*Math.PI/180;
var phi2 = 70*Math.PI/180;
var n = (Math.log(Math.cos(phi1)) - Math.log(Math.cos(phi2)))/
    (-Math.log(Math.tan(phi1/2 + Math.PI/4)) + Math.log(Math.tan(phi2/2 + Math.PI/4)));
var rho0 = (Math.cos(phi1)*Math.pow(Math.tan(phi1/2 + Math.PI/4),n))/
    (n*Math.pow(Math.tan(phi0/2 + Math.PI/4),n));

function ConformalConicLambertProjection() {};
ConformalConicLambertProjection.prototype = new GProjection();
ConformalConicLambertProjection.prototype.fromPixelToLatLng = function(pixel, z) {
    var x1 = (-0.0034375*(Math.pow(2,7 + z) - pixel.x))/Math.pow(2,z);
    var y1 = -0.0017254901960784311*Math.pow(2,1 - z)*
        (pixel.y - 405.68181818181824*Math.pow(2,-1 + z));
    var rho = Math.sqrt(2.143305952697287 + Math.pow(x1,2) - 
        2.9280067982826044*y1 + Math.pow(y1,2));
    var t = Math.asin(x1/rho);
    var lng = 78.17779218926289*t-100;
    var lat = 28.64788975654*(-3.141592653589793 + 
        4*Math.atan(2.004758218840869/Math.pow(rho,1.3644598756425434575)));
    return new GLatLng(lat, lng);
};
ConformalConicLambertProjection.prototype.fromLatLngToPixel = function(latLng, z) {
    var t = Math.PI/180*(100 + latLng.lng())*n;
    var rho = (Math.cos(phi1)*Math.pow(Math.tan(phi1/2. + Math.PI/4.),n))/
        (n*Math.pow(Math.tan((Math.PI/180*latLng.lat())/2. + Math.PI/4.),n));
    var x1 = rho*Math.sin(t);
    var y1 = rho0 - rho*Math.cos(t);
    x = Math.round(Math.pow(2,z)*(128 + 290.9090909090909*x1));
    y = Math.round(Math.pow(2,-1 + z)*(405.68181818181824 - 579.5454545454546*y1));
    return new GPoint(x,y);
};
ConformalConicLambertProjection.prototype.tileCheckRange = function(tileIndex, zoom, bs) {
    if(0 <= tileIndex.x && tileIndex.x < Math.pow(2,zoom) &&
       0 <= tileIndex.y && tileIndex.y < Math.pow(2,zoom-1)) {
         return true;}
    else { return false; };
};

function load() {
  if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {

    var lambertTileLayer = new GTileLayer(
        new GCopyrightCollection(), 1, 4);
    lambertTileLayer.getTileUrl = function(tile, zoom) {
        return "Tiles/ConformalConicLambertTile_" + tile.x + "_" + tile.y + "_" + zoom + ".png";
    };
    var lambertMap = new GMapType([lambertTileLayer],
        new ConformalConicLambertProjection(), "ConformalConicLambert",
        {tileSize:256});

    var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"), {mapTypes:[lambertMap]});

    // Add the controls
    map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl());
    map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.9251,-100), 1);


  } else {
    document.getElementById('map').style.backgroundColor = '#DDDDDD';
    document.getElementById('map').innerHTML = 'Sorry, your browser does not appear to be compatible with Google maps.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Lambert conformal conic and Lambert equal area azimuthal aren't the same. This code is difficult because there are a lot of hard-coded values. At minimum, you would need to change the setCenter and phi0/phi1/phi2 values. Beyond that, I don't know. Sorry!

Comment: can you tell by the code if it is that or not ? as in the description on his page it says: "The Lambert conformal conic projection implemented with the Google Maps API." and the link to the page is titled: "The US depicted using a Lambert conformal conic projection."

Comment: Because the lines `var x1 = rho*Math.sin(t); var y1 = rho0 - rho*Math.cos(t)` clearly implement equations (1) and (2) on the Mathworld site, you can be reasonably confident this is a version of the LCC and not the Lambert equal area azimuthal projection. But I agree with @mkennedy: hard-coding the parameters makes this code almost unreadable and practically unmaintainable. If I had to use it I would start over with the MathWorld equations and make it flexible enough to vary all the parameters.

Comment: yes i did compare this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_azimuthal_equal-area_projection and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_conformal_conic_projection and the java code above does really only look like the later. im just going to have to go back over it from scratch using either the mathworld / wikipedia formulas. ill leave the question open for now in case any one want to do it for me, i might even open it up for bounty.