# How to access Shapefile metadata using OGR?

Tags: shapefile, gdal, ogr

I'm trying to use ogrinfo to get some details on a shapefile I downloaded.  Currently, the only way I know how to do this is to load it into QGIS and manually click around to find any information on it, like opening the attribute table.

I just want to be able to see any metadata is tagged along with the features.  If I do:

```
ogrinfo -al USA_adm0.shp
```

I can see at the beginning there is a lot of useful information, but then it flies past with all the feature data.

Can someone help me out?

## EDIT

This is what I get on my mac using the -ro and -so flag, doesn't seem to be much help.

```
->ogrinfo -ro -so USA_adm0.shp
INFO: Open of `USA_adm0.shp'
      using driver `ESRI Shapefile' successful.
1: USA_adm0 (Polygon)
```

Comment: There are various ways in which you can see this info in an userfirendly manner, but this will depend upon your OS. You could for example pipe the output to a file, or use your bash/command line's pagination feature. We need more information about your OS, and where you are running the command.

Comment: In regards to your EDIT part, don't forget to look closely at the usage of `ogrinfo --help` where it needs you to specify `ogrinfo datasource_name layer` and you forgot to add a `layer` (so it listed the layers for you instead). Using `-al`, it will list info on All Layers without you specifying a layer.

Comment: Hi dvreed77, did you resolve this issue? there doesn't seem to be an answer on this thread that addresses the fact that `-ro -so` doesn't do much. I am experiencing the same problem.

Comment: Hi @Vlad, the `-geom=NO` flag did the trick for me

Comment: `ogrinfo -al -ro -so shapefile.shp` worked for me to get all the information

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[ogrinfo](http://www.gdal.org/ogrinfo.html) can shorten the output considerably using the `-so` flag.

> -so: Summary Only: supress listing of features, show only the summary information like projection, schema, feature count and extents.

So
`ogrinfo -ro -so file.shp` should give a summary of the metadata.

And

> -al:
>   List all features of all layers (used instead of having to give layer names as arguments).

Would certainly give you a lot of info on the other hand if used by itself!

And if you want to see metadata for individual or a range of features, there is the `-fid`, `-where`, and `-sql` flags which do that.

Lastly, `-geom` will act as a master toggle for the geometry info.

> -geom={YES/NO/SUMMARY}:
>   (starting with GDAL 1.6.0) If set to NO, the feature dump will not display the geometry. If set to SUMMARY, only a summary of the geometry will be displayed. If set to YES, the geometry will be reported in full OGC WKT format. Default value is YES.

There is a [FAQVector Wiki with examples for GDAL command line utilities](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQVector) that also gives some other tips =)

Comment: Thanks SaultDon.  I edited my post to show you what happens when I try the `-so` flag

Comment: It seems the `-geom=NO` is something that I was expecting.  Thanks!

Comment: This just prints the name of the first layer for me. Why is that? Versions prior to 3.4.1 behaved the way like you stated.

Answer (score 7):

You may try:

```
ogrinfo -al USA_adm0.shp >> output.txt
```

All the information will be redirected into a text file called `output.txt` in the folder in which the command was invoked (but a richer relative or absolute path can also be used)

Comment: OR; > ogrinfo -al USA_adm0.shp | head -30 (top 30 lines)

Comment: Thanks. Other command did not work for me with GDAL 3.4.1