# Determining unknown Coordinate Reference System based on ref points

Tags: coordinate-system

How do I find a projection to a target CRS (Coordinate Reference System) based on a number of reference points?

**Reference Points**

```
Lat Lng                                -> Unknown CRS (X, Y)

29.999999999999456, 10.0               -> 0, 0
29.999942188937776, 10.099416075499747 -> 10000, 0
52.51051013417886, 13.430682115106462  -> 229459, 2511140
52.420591784398034, 12.98406698769891  -> 200000, 2500000
52.44802435357121, 11.492633733515229  -> 100000, 2500000
```

From the data above it seems, the unknown CRS has its **origin at 30.0, 10.0** and the **unit is in meters**. My closest guess based on the tools recommended in related questions are:

[Esri:102014](http://epsg.io/102014) - Europe_Lambert_Conformal_Conic

[Esri:102031](http://epsg.io/102031) - Europe_Equidistant_Conic

However, trying to transform the coordinates using the CRS above does not yield the correct target reference points.

**Disclaimer:** I have read the related questions ([Determining unknown Coordinate System using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/114408) and [Find CRS (coordinate reference system) based on known location and coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119070))

The EPSG-Registry and Projfinder tools recommended in those questions did not yield a result.

Comment: If you have access to ArcGIS Desktop, create xy data layers for both sets of coordinates (include an ID field and give the corresponding points the same ID. Identify the lat/lon values as ETRS89 or WGS84. Leave the other values as "unknown coordinate system". Start with 102013 and start adjusting the false easting/northing values of the data frame's coordinate system to see if you can get a match.

Comment: I do not have access to ArcGIS. However, you gave me the idea to "bruteforce" the various parameters of the projections that gave the "closest" results. Using the `org.geotools` java api and some parameter fuzzing  techniques I found the projection is accurately described by `Lambert_Conformal_Conic_2SP` with `central_meridian=10,latitude_of_origin=30,standard_parallel_1=40,standard_parallel_2=60` :)