# Projecting Microstation .dgn that has no coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, microstation

I have a set of .dgn drawings that have been sent to me from a client.  All of which were never assigned to a coordinate system upon creating them.  I am attempting to assign a coordinate system to this .dgn data and export to AutoCAD which I will then export to ArcMap.  Is this process possible?  Is it possible to Export Microstation .dgn files straight to a shapefile?

Comment: It is possible if and only if the drawing was originally made in a projected coordinate system. If you can answer these questions, it might be easier to fix: First, are you familiar with projections or not? Do you know the approximate real world location of the project? Do the coordinates shown when you look at the .dgn fit in a projected system you know? You can take a look at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/119070/find-crs-coordinate-reference-system-based-on-known-location-and-coordinates) for a tool that can help finding your projection.

Comment: Georeferencing http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/about-georeferencing-cad-datasets.htm

Comment: Check File > Export in MicroStation to see what you can export it to. I don't see Shapefile, but I do have an older MicroStation version. Still, I don't see why you would need to go via AutoCAD. ArcMap should be capable of importing DGN data directly, albeit in a fairly rudimentary manner.

Comment: As for Coordinate System, in MicroStation you can set an Auxillary Coordinate System (ACS). But as others have said, that obviously depends on your knowing what coordinate system was used. But if you can set that then I believe the data can be exported using that set of coordinates.

Comment: Thank you all so much for commenting!  Gabriel C.  So I need them to be re-assigned (if possible) to Projection: Lambert Conformal Conic, Coordinate System: VA 1983 State Plane Virginia South FIPS 4502 (US Feet).  However they were originally drawn without a projection so based on your first comment it looks like I'll have to find a work around... Thanks again..