# How to identify unknown coordinate system?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, united-kingdom

Now I'm trying to convert unknown coordinate system to Google Maps (WGS84?). How can I identify what kind of projection am I dealing with? I'm inspecting www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk. Route response returns json with:

```
name:"Epsom, Epsom Railway Station (Stop N)"
coords:"-29903.75584,5319390.31291"

name:"Epsom, Epsom Race Course (W-bound)"
coords:"-28583.17541,5323006.72201"
```

[link to route search result](http://www.travelinesoutheast.org.uk/se/XSLT_GEOOBJECT_REQUEST?language=en&command=bothDirections&line=set:06406:F::y08:1&hideBannerInfo=1&coordOutputFormat=MRCV)

Comment: Are you dealing with a shapefile?

Comment: these are just projected coordinates with unit in meters... what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Identifying an unknown coordinate system can be quite a chore, especially if the data is old (older than 1984 at least), where did the data come from? Does your source have some metadata associated with it?

Comment: There are some hints at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown

Comment: I need to convert those coordinates to format acceptable by Google Maps (i.e. ~ 51.334050, -0.269224). In browser developer tools network section I can find json file with starting and ending point coordinates and path but I don't know how to convert them.

Here's json: http://goo.gl/UrqTHI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Eastings in the geojson are Google mercator coordinates (EPSG:3857), but Northing is calculated froma virtual axis 12000000m North of the equator, positive southwards.

You could use a custom CRS like this:

```
+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=-12000000 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +axis=esu +no_defs
```

But unfortunately, the special Google Mercator conversion does not work that way.

So you have to calculate new northing from `12000000 - old Northing`, then do the standard Google Mercator reprojection from 3857 to 4326.

The result looks like this, on an OpenStreetMap background:

[image]