# Inspecting lat long of shapefile using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, fields-attributes

I have a shapefile that shows up in QGIS and ArcGIS correctly.

But when I inspect the attributes of the layer it does not have latitude or longitude.

I need to extract the coordinate system so I'm looking for the lat/longs using QGIS.

Comment: May be related to this question "Identifying Coordinate System of Shapefile when Unknown?": https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown

Comment: Beware of posting illegible images in your question. Usually this is an issue with alternate devices (phone, etc), but the attribute printout isn't even legible on an HD monitor.

Comment: Just convert shapefile to geojson. You can see vertices of your polygon as coordinates

Comment: The data may not be in degrees lat/long, not all coordinate systems use degrees as a unit of measure.

Answer (score 5):

That's what shapefiles do: keep the coordinates in a binary where you cannot see them.
 In qgis go to the field calculator, ad a field "x": double, length 12 with 8 precision, and then write "$x" in the calculator, the same for "y"; if you want the nodes of a polygon or a line, first extract them (there's an option in the toolbox), then do the field calculator procedure.

Comment: Or, more simple, go for Vector->Geometry tools->add geometry column

Comment: he said he was looking for latitude and longitude, not for area and perimeter

Comment: If the x and y values aren't in lat/long format, right click on the layer and save a copy in WGS 84 coordinate system. Then re-calculate the x and y columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the coordinate system in the 'general' tab of the layer properties dialog box (right click on the layer to bring up the properties option). You can also find coordinate system info in the .prj file of the shapefile (if you are indeed using a shapefile).