# How to transform a shapefile's projection in ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcmap, shapefile, coordinate-system

I am working with a series of shapefiles of France, which were created privately by someone (as opposed to an official institution). We can call them the P-maps. There is no .prj file associated with them. When I open them in QGIS or ArcMap, and set their coordinate system to be WGS84, they "look alright". However, they don't overlay with a correct shapefile of France in WGS84 (a map in WGS84 from the IGN, let's call it IGN) , so another projection was used (you can see the picture, the IGN shapefile is circled in blue; one of the P-maps is pointed in red).

I know I could potentially try to identify the correct projection by trying each individual projection one by one, by I am weary of using this method, as I am not sure that this person correctly georeferenced these P-maps. I think that they establish them by creating the shapefile from an image that was not georeferenced.

Is there a way to define a transformation to each file (I have around 50 P-maps, and they all align to each other) so that  GIS would define the right coordinates systems, having the comparison point of the IGN shapefile in the WGS84 projection? Something like when you georeference a raster map. Since all the  maps align, I could apply this transformation to each one of them.

The layer extent: 
top 590.9218000
right 620.0
bottom 30.0
left 20.02860

And the file you can [download](https://www.valeriarueda.org/app/download/13676379529/cantons.zip?t=1525448298)

[image]

Comment: There are a number of [suggestions to help determine the projection of the dataset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown) in a prior question.

Comment: If you are stuck transforming (rather than identifying) the coordinate system then please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and QGIS you wish to ask about in this particular question. In ArcGIS Desktop I suggest looking at Spatial Adjustment.

Comment: Please edit your question with the extents of the shapefile or where you got it (if public). Even if you're tired of checking multiple CRS, others may not be!

Comment: The actual official projection for France is ''RGF93/Lambert93'' (EPSG:2154) one other common french projection where ''Lambert zone II'' (EPSG:7421), you could try these one first

Comment: @JR, thank you, this is helpful as I had not tried espg7421.. Actually the person who created the files mentioned he used "Lambert II etendu". But I have tried anything with a familiar name (espg: 7402, 7412, 27572, 27872, 7421, esri 108582, se-org: 7152, 9115), perhaps mistankenly, but unsuccesfully.