# Two layers, same coordinate system, wont show up

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I have vector two sets of vector layers that won't show up together. One set shows up together and the other set together etc but they are of the same area.

The layers I was given did not have a defined spatial reference which I manually projected as the same as the data frame I specified so all layers now have same CRS...yet not showing up together. I have noticed they appear to have different extents... What should I do?

Comment: Welcome to GIS Se. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. This is one of our most frequent questions -- You have likely clobbered the correct spatial reference or gave the wrong definition to start, but it's impossible to tell because you haven't given any details. Please [Edit] the question to describe your inputs, the exact steps you took, and what the data looks like now. Please choose one of the two tagged packages for solving the problem, since tagging both makes this two questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Layers with same coordinate system should align/overlap in ArcMap but do not?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20572/layers-with-same-coordinate-system-should-align-overlap-in-arcmap-but-do-not). This question should help too: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown. When you say "The layers I was given did not have a defined spatial reference", that's almost certainly not true, the layers do have a spatial reference but you don't know what it is. Your first step is to find out.

Comment: Thanks Dan C, the layers' spatial reference show up as 'unknown' so I defined them as the same one as my data frame and nothing...

Comment: What appears to be the only difference is one is showing up in lat/long and the other in m....any help in fixing this?