# My XY data is missing - what do I do?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

My xy data (which is in lat/long) wont show up with my other layers which are also shown in lat/long. They appear in two different places.. any advice?

Comment: Duplicate of [Two layers, same coordinate system, wont show up](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/327931/two-layers-same-coordinate-system-wont-show-up). If your question was closed as a duplicate, there's usually a good reason. please don't re-post it.

Comment: They could be in lat/long and still use different CRS, did you check that they are correctly defined for each of your layer

Comment: I will try that, thanks J.R.

Answer (score 1):

You may be defining the X field as the longitude and Y as latitude.

When I get in a hurry I flip them and my data shows up in very wrong locations.

Comment: Hey! Yes they are all right, I wish it was that simple!

Comment: And the coordinates are similar to the coordinates of your other data sets?

Comment: Yes, its a tricky one