# Defining and changing unknown CRS into WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, shapefile, qgis-3

I came across a shapefile (no information available about the original CRS) with some unknown Reference System (City of Stuttgart in Germany). Example of coordinates looks like `3465878, 5482952`. I assume it is lat/lon.

How can I change the CRS to the decimal system of WGS84 with QGIS 3?

Is it possible to overlay it to another shapefile with the borders and match the CRS?

Comment: You need to determine the original CRS to be able to apply the correct transformation to WGS84. see this to learn how :https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown

Comment: Have you tried one of Zones from DHDN / 3-degree Gauß-Krüger, or one Zone from ETRS89 UTM North?

Comment: `3465878, 5482952 (I assume lat/lon))` Obviously not lat long otherwise you'd expect lat values +/- 90 degrees and long +/- 180 degrees but your values are in the 100,000's so more likely to be units of metres

Answer (score 6):

**Step 1.** Defining unknown CRS

I would suggest double-checking if suddenly there is a [`prj`](https://vsp.pnnl.gov/help/Vsample/ESRI_PRJ_File.htm)-file, placed in the shapefile location.

If not, you can try using [projfinder](http://projfinder.com/). For instance, when one tried it with provided coordinates `(3465878, 5482952)`

[image: example]

There are two options:

- [EPSG:31467](https://epsg.io/31467) Name:DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger zone 3, as was mentioned by [@MrXsquared](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/107424/mrxsquared)
- [EPSG:31463](https://epsg.io/31463) Name:DHDN / 3-degree Gauss zone 3 (deprecated)

I would proceed with [EPSG:31467](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/dhdn-gauss-kruger-zone-3/) because EPSG:31463 is not maintained anymore.

> **EPSG:31467**
>
> DHDN / 3-degree Gauss-Kruger Zone 3
>
> WGS84 Bounds: 7.5000, 47.2700, 10.5000, 55.0600
>   Projected Bounds: 3386564.9400, 5237917.9109, 3613579.2251, 6104500.7393
>   Scope: Large and medium scale topographic mapping and engineering survey, cadastral survey
>   Last Revised: Sept. 24, 2008
>   Area: Germany - 7.5°E to 10.5°E

**Step 2.** Changing unknown CRS into WGS84

It is already a well-known topic in the GIS domain. So, I would highly suggest to simply [searching it online](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=qgis+3+transform+shapefile+coordinate+system&t=hk&ia=web).

There are several references that I may point out:

- [QGIS Docs | 7.1.3. moderate Follow Along: Saving a Dataset to Another CRS](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/de/docs/training_manual/vector_analysis/reproject_transform.html#moderate-fa-saving-a-dataset-to-another-crs)
- [How to Change the Projection of a Shapefile Using QGIS](https://www.gislounge.com/how-to-change-the-projection-of-a-shapefile-using-qgis/)
- [Step Three: Export your shapefile as WGS 84](http://jonathansoma.com/tutorials/mapping/change-crs-with-qgis/)

**Step 3.** Overlaying with another shapefile

The vital trick is that all of your shapefiles that have to be overlapped must match the same CRS.

Comment: Very useful website. Will bookmark it.

Comment: Yeap, Mr. [@spacedman](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/865/spacedman) first demonstrated it to me

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure this is GK3 (EPSG:31467).

Go to layer properties --> Source and set source CRS to EPSG:31467

Then do the transformation (Export as...) to WGS84.

If everything is located perfectly, you are good to go. (If not, I was wrong about the CRS...)