# Using Python to convert from more than one CRS

Tags: python, coordinate-system

I have a Python function which converts Eastings and Northings to Latitude and Longitude

```
if line_count == 0:
                    keys = row
                    print('keys', keys)
                    line_count += 1
                else:
                    inProj = Proj(init='epsg:27700') # British National Grid
                    outProj = Proj(init='epsg:4326') # WGS84
                    x1, y1 = row[1], row[2]  # easting, northing
                    x2, y2 = transform(inProj, outProj, x1, y1)
                    row[1], row[2] = y2, x2
                    
                    json_doc = {}
```

At the moment it converts from epsg:27700 (British National Grid) to WGS84, however there is a possibility I will get TM75 Irish Grid too. Is there any way I can get Python to recognised which CRS is applicable for the conversion?

Comment: If the question is can you get Python to automatically detect SRID from a given source with no info, then no. But there are coordinate predictor tools out there. See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Identifying Coordinate System of Shapefile when Unknown?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown)

Comment: Your other option, if it's only ever one or the other, is to write a pair of Regular Expression patterns that can distinguish between the two. But that only works if the two don't have meaningful overlap in terms of the coordinates used.

Comment: Yes it's only ever one or the other. The eastings/northings are given to me in CSV format

Comment: both OSGB and TM75 are plain decimal numbers in the 0-100000's range so there is no way to tell them apart