# Converting coordinates in Harrisburg (Pennsylvania) to WGS84 using GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinate-system, convert, geopandas, united-states

I have points in Harrisburg, PA in a GeoPandas (Python) GeoDataFrame with no CRS.

How do I convert them to WGS84?

I'm trying to do something like below but don't know what CRS to initially set the GeoDataFrame to.

```py
my_points.set_crs('<what do I put here?>').to_crs('epsg:4326')
```

Here is what `my_points` looks like:

```
                           geometry
0    POINT (2243939.780 360357.900)
1    POINT (2257434.260 344832.350)
2    POINT (2236659.870 371819.840)
3    POINT (2245296.700 332006.600)
4    POINT (2251921.980 340172.260)
```

Comment: 2271? https://epsg.io/2271-1711

Comment: Try some of the solutions here perhaps https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7863/173550

Comment: You may also try the http://projfinder.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates I have are in feet, in the coordinate system **NAD83 / Pennsylvania South (ft US)**. The EPSG code for it is **EPSG:2272**. I found that out by trying the epsg code of a data set I have for the same region, though the link in the answer by Joe Be would certainly have gotten be there:

[Identifying Coordinate System of Shapefile when Unknown?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7839/identifying-coordinate-system-of-shapefile-when-unknown/7863#7863) .

To convert it to WGS84 with Python GeoPandas was:

```py
my_points.set_crs('epsg:2272').to_crs('epsg:4326')
```