# Spatial reference for dummies?

Tags: coordinate-system, references, gis-principle

Can anyone recommend a good reference or tutorial that explains the principles of spatial references, projections, and coordinate systems?

We are a small team of programmers working with GIS technology, and we often get snagged when working with data in different SRS/CS because we don't understand the concepts.

Comment: spatial referencing isn't for dummies :-)

Comment: Many of the answers to [What strategies, criteria, or rules to use for selecting coordinate systems?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2769) also fit perfectly here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally, for the cliff's notes I find the ESRI ArcGIS desktop software [help system](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Projection_basics_for_GIS_professionals/003r00000002000000/) useful, and and also the ESRI book *[Understanding Map Projections](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/documentation/ao_/710Understanding_Map_Projections.pdf)*, its first 30 pages are not unlike a short textbook, followed by ~70 pages of appendix on individual projections, their uses, strengths, weaknesses, etc.

From these, you'll quickly understand all the pieces of a complete SR - spheroid + datum + meridian + unit of measure => GCS; and projection + parameters + unit of measure + GCS => PCS.

For all the math, try the classic USGS Professional Paper 1395 by John P. Synder - *Map Projections - A Working Manual*. You might find a PDF somewhere if you google it.

Finally, take a look at the 'documentation' links at the bottom of the page for the [Proj.4](http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/) library.

And as a DB of spatial references, I tend to refer to http://www.spatialreference.org/ or another ESRI [list](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/usingspatialreferences.html) provided as part of the docs for their ArcGIS Server REST API.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

Answering a question about [the difference between a projection and a datum](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/664/whats-the-difference-between-a-projection-and-a-datum), Bill Huber links to his article in the [Directions Magazine](http://www.directionsmag.com/articles/reprojecting-grids/124167) where he gives introductory explanations of georeferencing, datums, spheroids, and the like.

As short and concise as it can be!

Answer (score 6):

I think Carlos Furuti's tutorial is a really good resource.

http://www.progonos.com/furuti/MapProj/CartIndex/cartIndex.html

Answer (score 3):

The [PostGIS in action book](http://www.postgis.us/) has a great chapter, [6 - Spatial reference system considerations](http://www.postgis.us/chapter_06),  on these subjects, although it is (of course) a bit targeted at PostGIS use. Well worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

The OGP have lots of useful information on geodesy, try:

http://www.ogp.org.uk/pubs/373-01.pdf

They also have a GIGS (Geospatial Integrity of GeoScience Software) program, more info here and also via OGP:

http://www.cain-barnes.com/index.php/geospatial-integrity-of-geoscience-software

Answer (score 0):

I just ran across NOAA's "[What is a Datum](http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/datum.html)".

They seem to have more info on [vertical datums](http://geodesy.noaa.gov/datums/vertical/VerticalDatums.shtml) than other sites I've seen.

(I guess *data* is no longer the plural form of *datum*.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one for Arc that goes through several scenarios using vector data:
http://blog.geographyforever.org/2013/03/25/working-with-spatial-reference-systems-in-arcgis/