# What criteria should be used to select a project CRS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I've been using QGIS for a little while now, but I am still a bit confused about coordinate systems. There is plenty of guidance about **how** to change project and layer CRS, on-the-fly transformation etc, but I can't find anything which explains fairly simply **why** you should use a particular CRS in preference to another. Does it depend on the data sources (if any) which I intend to use? Or the size of the area to be covered (eg a few square kilometres vs a whole country)? Or the locale?

I've tried searching for tutorials etc which can shed a bit more light, but haven't come up with anything yet.

Comment: Perhaps this post might help: [What strategies, criteria, or rules to use for selecting coordinate systems?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2769/what-strategies-criteria-or-rules-to-use-for-selecting-coordinate-systems)